# nginx reverse proxy stripe domain

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I trying to stripe part of a domain to pass it in reverse proxy

```
server {
server_name *.dr.domain.com;
listen X.X.X.;

set $headerDR $host;

location / {
    proxy_set_header Accept-Encoding "";
    proxy_set_header Host "DOMAIN WITHOUT .dr.domain.com";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_pass http://x.x.x.x;

    sub_filter "DOMAIN WITHOUT .dr.domain.com" "$headerDR";
    sub_filter_once off;

}
```

How can do this please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the regular expression version of the `server_name` directive, you can use a named capture to extract the part of the domain you need.

For example:

```
server_name  ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.dr\.domain\.com$;
proxy_set_header Host $subdomain;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for details.